# If/else is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]In this code `if/else` is not working. Am I making any mistake? `data.success` contains `true/false`. If I code like this if `(data.success === true)` then else block is working and if block is not working and vise versa.

```
$scope.verifyMobile = function () {
   var otp = {
      "otp": $scope.mobile.otp
   };
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'verify_mobile',
      data: otp,
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      if (data.success) {
          $scope.verified = true;
          $scope.sms_sent = false;
      } else {
          alert(data.message);
      }
   }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
   });
};
```

Comment: try to print the data type of the value data.success, `alert(typeof data.success)` before the if condition, becuase `undefined` and `null` can also be checked with the same if condition, in case your `data.success` is `undefined` or `null` then else part will trigger

Comment: @Scary he already told `angularjs` probably he is a beginner in stackoverflow and coding that is why he tagged as `java`

Comment: `if (data.success)` will return true as long as `data.success` is not undefined nor null. Use `if (data.success == true)` instead.

Comment: isnt success deprecated ? try to use then

Comment: when I do alert(typeof data.success), it returns object

Comment: once check whats in data. by alert(data)

Comment: Change it to `data.success[0]`, the success object is an array basing from your screenshot.

Comment: You all guys are amazing and very helpful. And a very warm thanks to Adrian who identified the real cause. @Zigma thanks as well for your comment it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the data.success and data.message to data.success[0] and data.message[0], because that are not boolean values you returning array in response that's why you have to take it in a array format. Try below code.

```
$scope.verifyMobile = function () {
        var otp = {
            "otp": $scope.mobile.otp
        };
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'verify_mobile',
            data: otp,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.success[0]) {
                $scope.verified = true;
                $scope.sms_sent = false;
            } else {
                alert(data.message[0]);
            }
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your data.success is not contains boolean value.
So before your if-else block try to print type of data.success

```
console.log(typeof data.success);
```

And see is it boolean if not then just resolve it.

Comment: when I do alert(typeof data.success), it returns object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.success()` use `.then()`.

Response will return an object you should check the response as below

```
$scope.httpRequest = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  }).then(function(success) {
    if (success.data.userId === 1) {
      $scope.name = 'Jason Statham'
    } else {
      $scope.name = 'Cristiano Ronaldo'
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkrjkkt8/)</kbd>